# trouble in laptop with setxkbmap

Tags: configuration, xinit, setxkbmap

So I have a .xsession config that works well in several pc, but with a laptop I recently set up I have some issues.

When I `systemctl halt` [or `suspend`] the laptop, then when it starts again [or wakes up], most of the times (but not always) the following two configs are like reset to the default (like if they were never executed)

1. config screens via `xrandr --output ...`
2. swap keys via `setxkbmap -option caps:swapescape`
   Furthermore, if I unplug and plug again a keyboard, then 2 happens always.

The worst is that when issue 2 happens, then for setxkbmap to work again I need to reboot (since I got `Error loading new keyboard description` for any setxkbmap command).

Any ideas how to address these two issues?